# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string that's not null or empty

Tags: java, integer

getting an Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8801609054" even though it can properly read the format.

I'm using

```
Integer.parseInt("8801609054");
```

to do this. I've found people with similar error usually had null or empty values but this one has a value so I'm not sure where the error is coming from.

Comment: The literal 8801609054 of type int is out of range

Comment: largest possible integer is 2147483647

Comment: Use a `long` or a `BigInteger` here... Alternative: `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number you passed as a string is too large. The largest integer allowed is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2147483647). Maybe you should work with `BigDecimal` instead.

Answer (score 1):

8801609054 is larger than the maximum integer value (primitive int) in Java. You can compare it with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and confirm.